# Lastpass iOS autofill filter

Tags: ios, autofill, lastpass

I'm trying to link our iOS app to our website with Lastpass. For most sites/apps, Lastpass will filter your list of passwords to the ones that match the app you're trying to log into. For example, if you have a password for mysite.com in LP, if you open up the mysite.com iOS app, the list of passwords will be filtered to the one for mysite.com.

Our app does not filter. When we tap the password field, all available passwords show up and we have to navigate to the password for our website to autofill. We would like this to work like it does for other app/site combos.

I have already deployed the app association file to my website and added the Entitlements to the app (applinks and webcredentials) but it still doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Did you add the site to your app's Associated Domains Entitlement? You need to do that in addition to adding the Apple App Site Association file to your site which you said you've done already.

Documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/password_autofill/about_the_password_autofill_workflow

Comment: This was a good suggestion. I had the Associated entitlement but I didn't have the Auto Fill entitlement. I enabled that but Last Pass still doesn't filter.